# Error firing up meteor app in android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I'm getting this error when trying to run using `meteor run android`:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20150430-17:43:21.410(-4) (android:cordova.js:927) Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
I20150430-17:43:24.425(-4) (android:cordova.js:1169) deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
I20150430-17:43:24.450(-4) (android:cordova.js:1162) Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
I20150430-17:43:24.487(-4) (android:cordova.js:1162) Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
I20150430-17:43:24.516(-4) (android:cordova.js:1162) Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

Running inside an Ubuntu VirtualBox. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its a new bug in Meteor/Cordova, running `meteor run android --release 1.0.3.1` works.